# Hyperledger fabric: TLS Handshake fails with error "no TLS certificate sent" using intermediate CA certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, hyperledger-fabric

I am using Hyperledger Fabric V1.4 to deploy a blockchain in azure using Raft, I created my certificates using openssl and signed them with an external CA, and the CA is not a root CA so, I have an intermediate CA certificate.

I created my genesis block using a configtx.yaml and this msp folder structure:

configtx.yaml

```
    Organizations:
    - &ordererOrg
        Name: orderer
        ID: orderer
        MSPDir: /crypto/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('orderer.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('orderer.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('orderer.admin')" 
    Capabilities:
        Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
            V1_4_3: true
        Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
            V1_4_2: true
        Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
            V1_4_2: true
    Application: &ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Readers"
            Writers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
            Admins:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
        OrdererType: solo
        BatchTimeout: 2s
        BatchSize:
            MaxMessageCount: 10
            AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
            PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
        Kafka:
            Brokers:
                - 127.0.0.1:9092
        Organizations:
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Readers"
            Writers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
            Admins:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
            BlockValidation:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Channel: &ChannelDefaults
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Readers"
            Writers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
            Admins:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Profiles:
    SampleEtcdRaftProfile:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            Addresses:
                - orderer1.xxxx.eastus.aksapp.io:443
                - orderer2.xxxx.eastus.aksapp.io:443
            Organizations:
            - *ordererOrg
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                    - Host: orderer1
                    Port: 7050
                    ClientTLSCert: /crypto/orderers/orderer1/tls/server.crt
                    ServerTLSCert: /crypto/orderers/orderer1/tls/server.crt
                    - Host: orderer2
                    Port: 7050
                    ClientTLSCert: /crypto/orderers/orderer2/tls/server.crt
                    ServerTLSCert: /crypto/orderers/orderer2/tls/server.crt
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *ordererOrg
        Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *ordererOrg
```

MSP folder structure:

```
+ /crypto
  configtx.yaml
  + msp
    + cacerts > ca.crt
    + tlscacerts > ca.crt
    + intermediatecerts > intermediate.crt
    + tlsintermediatecerts > intermediate.crt
    + admincerts > admin.crt
  + orderers
    + orderer1/tls > server.crt
    + orderer2/tls > server.crt
```

I created my genesis block using this:

```
configtxgen -profile SampleEtcdRaftProfile -outputBlock genesis.block -channelID mychannel
```

Inside my orderer the msp structure is like this:

```
+ /var/hyperledger/orderer
  genesis.block
  + msp
    + cacerts > ca.crt
    + intermediatecerts > intermediate.crt
    + admincerts > admin.crt
    + signcerts > cert.pem
    + keystore > key.pem
  + tls
    server.crt
    server.key
    ca.crt
    intermediate.crt
```

And these are my env variables:

```
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/chain.crt
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=false
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/chain.crt
ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/chain.crt
```

I'm not sure why the structure is different and the tls files are somewhere else but I am copying the configuration from the [azure hyperledger template](https://github.com/Azure/Hyperledger-Fabric-on-Azure-Kubernetes-Service) That I have already used successfuly.

Now my orderers are running but orderer1 keeps starting a new election and orderer 2 becomes precandidate and finally fails with a TLS handshake error.

These are the error logs in orderer1:

```
2021-03-24 17:37:49.717 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO a16 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=testchainid node=1
2021-03-24 17:37:49.717 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO a17 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=testchainid node=1
2021-03-24 17:37:49.717 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO a18 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=testchainid node=1
2021-03-24 17:37:49.717 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO a19 1 [logterm: 1, index: 2] sent MsgPreVote request to 2 at term 1 channel=testchainid node=1
2021-03-24 17:37:49.718 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] send -> INFO a1a Successfully sent StepRequest to 2 after failed attempt(s) channel=testchainid node=1
2021-03-24 17:37:52.406 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] func1 -> WARN a1b Certificate of unidentified node from 172.32.0.141:54008 for channel testchainid expires in less than -2562047h47m16.854775808s
2021-03-24 17:37:52.406 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a1c streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.Cluster grpc.method=Step grpc.peer_address=172.32.0.141:54008 error="no TLS certificate sent" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=269.221µs
```

These are the error logs in orderer2:

```
2021-03-24 21:40:51.240 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] logSendFailure -> ERRO 2e36 Failed to send StepRequest to 1, because: aborted channel=testchainid node=2
2021-03-24 21:40:52.239 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 2e37 2 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=testchainid node=2
2021-03-24 21:40:52.239 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 2e38 2 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=testchainid node=2
2021-03-24 21:40:52.239 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 2e39 2 received MsgPreVoteResp from 2 at term 1 channel=testchainid node=2
2021-03-24 21:40:52.239 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 2e3a 2 [logterm: 1, index: 2] sent MsgPreVote request to 1 at term 1 channel=testchainid node=2
2021-03-24 21:40:52.239 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] send -> INFO 2e3b Successfully sent StepRequest to 1 after failed attempt(s) channel=testchainid node=2
2021-03-24 21:40:54.042 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] func1 -> WARN 2e40 Certificate of unidentified node from 172.32.0.211:58714 for channel testchainid expires in less than -2562047h47m16.854775808s
2021-03-24 21:40:54.042 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 2e41 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.Cluster grpc.method=Step grpc.peer_address=172.32.0.211:58714 error="no TLS certificate sent" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=127.311µs
```

I have tried passing to the ROOTCAS env variables, the ca-root certificate only, the ca-intermediate certificate only, the appended chain in pem format first root then intermediate, the appended chain in reverse order and the array of ca and intermediate certificates, in every case I get the "no TLS certificate sent", except for the case with the ca certificate only, that gives me a "certificate signed by unknown authority" error.

This is how I appended my ca certificates:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
INTERMEDIATExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ROOTCERTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried openssl verify -CAfile chain.crt orderer1-tls.crt and returns OK.

I tested my urls with telnet and they are ok.

I have double checked all the values but I guess orderer wouldn't even be running if they weren't right and followed this [script](https://github.com/Azure/Hyperledger-Fabric-on-Azure-Kubernetes-Service/blob/72d5de82996bff8c9a8f09df8bc23cf84d1c1ec0/fabricTools/scripts/buildNetwork.sh#L100) from azure for the creation of the genesis block only adding the intermediate info.

Also while I'm testing I'm modifiing /etc/hosts file for DNS resolution, can this be the reason for my error?

Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with this env variable:

```
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=false
```

I'm not sure why its disabled in the azure template but changing it to true allowed the orderers to get consense.